# How to write this JPA query term?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables;

```
Create table Student (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(35),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Create table Course (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    student_id int,
    name varchar(35),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
    REFERENCES Student(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Query: find all course taken by the student "John".

```
Select C.name 
FROM Course C
JOIN Student S
  ON S.id=C.student_id 
WHERE S.name='John';
```

How to write this in JPA query langauge? How to write criteria involving two tables like this which are related by a foreign key?

```
public List<Course> findCourseByStudentName(String name) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Course> criteria = cb.createQuery(Course.class);
    Root<Course> courseRoot = criteria.from(Course.class);

    Join<Course,Student> courseStudent = courseRoot.join(Course_.student);
    criteria.select(courseRoot).where(cb.equal(courseStudent.get(Student_.name), "John"));

}
```

Edited:
This is the Student class, Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 35)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="student")
    Set<Course> courses;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCourses(Set<course> courses) {
        this.course = course;
    }        

    public Set<Course> getCourses() { 
       return courses; 
    }
}
```

This is the Course class, Course.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull 
    @ManyToOne( targetEntity = Student.class ) 
    @JoinColumn( name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") 
    private Student student; 

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 35)
    private String name;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setStudent(String student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public String getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: so in JPQL you did a "join", so perhaps do a join(...) in Criteria then. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql_criteria.html#Criteria_API_:_From_clause_joins

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Thank you. Will study these documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My latest edition gave the correct answer. Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must create two entities `Student` and `Course` and add at least `@ManyToOne` relationship in `Course`. Than you can use JPQL, something ike this:

```
    SELECT C.name
      FROM Cource C
INNER JOIN Student S
     WHERE S.name = :studentName
```

After that you should add parameter in query and get `List<String>` as result

Comment: Should the @OneToMany be placed in Student class? Since a Student has multiple courses. Please see my edited classes.

Comment: It's not necessary for this scenario, but if you want get cources as `Set<Cources>` from student class or use join from `Student` to `Cource` in JPQL - you should add it. Also it will be usefull to read about cascade operations and lazy loading

Comment: The above classes, I received this error "Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: registration-ds] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: Student, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(courses)]"}}".

Comment: In yours code in class `Cource` field `Student` must be not `String` but `Student` and that annotations @ManyToOne(
        targetEntity = Student.class
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "student_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id"
    )

Comment: " @ManyToOne( targetEntity = Student.class ) @JoinColumn( name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id" ) " should this be added to which method?

Comment: Also, where are you seeing "In yours code Student must be not String"? I don't see Student as a String.

Comment: In `Cource` class on field `Student` - change type from `String` to `Student`, add `@ManyToOne`as in previous comment  and delete `@Size` annotation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104560/discussion-between-d0dger-and-ling).